# System.getenv() method - deprecated or not?

Tags: java, environment-variables, system, deprecated

Many places suggest that the `System.getenv()` JDK method has been deprecated. Many places suggest that it has been reinstated.

Is there a better API that provides the functionality to get environment settings in subsequent JDKs?

Or is `System.getenv()` still the preferred way to get environment variables / properties?

Answer (score 6):

[`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--) and [`System.getenv(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) were introduced in the very early days of java, and then deprecated in Java 1.2(!).

Java 5 reinstated them (see [bug 4199068](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4199068)), and since there's been no sign of these methods going anywhere or even being deprecated again for the last dozen years or so, I think it's safe to assume that they're here to stay, and use them as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Java 8 API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) the method is not deprecated. It has references to `getenv(String)` but no other alternatives. Since `getenv()` returns a `Map<String,String>` from which you could just `get(String)` you may as well just call `getenv(String)` to get the value you are looking for else `null` if it is not defined. As those API docs are authoritative you can conclude that `getEnv()` is not deprecated in the current version Java nor is there a better recommended alternative other than `getenv(String)`. Given that that API was introduced in Java 1.5 it is also highly backwards compatible.